# How to Play Audio File Into Channel?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

How do you play an audio file from a Discord bot? Needs to play a local file, be in JS, and upon a certain message being sent it will join the user who typed the message, and will play the file to that channel.

Comment: There's no need for the bloat of Visual Studio .. way overkill .. you just need node.js and the dependencies via npm.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

GitHub Project: [LINK](https://github.com/NickJohn547745/DiscordBotSpeak)

In order to do this there are a few things you have to make sure of first.

1. Have FFMPEG installed & the environment path set for it in Windows [[link](http://adaptivesamples.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/)]
2. Have Microsoft Visual Studio (VS) installed [[link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691978&clcid=0x409)]
3. Have Node.js installed.[[link](https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.4.0/node-v7.4.0-x64.msi)]
4. Have Discord.js installed in VS.

From there the steps are quite simple. After making your project `index.js` you will start typing some code. Here are the steps:

1. Add the Discord.js dependency to the project;

`var Discord = require('discord.js');`

2. Create out client variable called *bot*;

`var bot = new Discord.Client();`
3. Create a Boolean variable to make sure that the system doesn't overload of requests;

`var isReady = true;`

4. Next make the function to intercept the correct message;

`bot.on('message', message =>{ENTER CODE HERE});`

5. Create an *if statement* to check if the message is correct & if the bot is ready;

`if (isReady && message.content === 'MESSAGE'){ENTER CODE HERE}`

6. Set the bot to unready so that it cannot process events until it finishes;

`isReady = false;`

7. Create a variable for the channel that the message-sender is currently in;

`var voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;`

8. Join that channel and keep track of all errors;

`voiceChannel.join().then(connection =>{ENTER CODE HERE}).catch(err => console.log(err));`

9. Create a refrence to and play the audio file;

`const dispatcher = connection.play('./audiofile.mp3');`

10. Slot to wait until the audio file is done playing;

`dispatcher.on("end", end => {ENTER CODE HERE});`

11. Leave channel after audio is done playing;

`voiceChannel.leave();`

12. Login to the application;

`bot.login('CLIENT TOKEN HERE');`

After you are all finished with this, make sure to check for any un-closed brackets or parentheses. i made this because it took my hours until I finally found a good solution so I just wanted to share it with anybody who is out there looking for something like this.

Comment: The current discord api requires to install discordjs/opus.

Answer (score 6):

thanks so much!

One thing I will say to help anyone else, is things like where it says ENTER CODE HERE on step 10, you put the code from step 11 IE:

```
dispatcher.on("end", end => voiceChannel.leave());
```

As a complete example, this is how I have used it in my message command IF block:

```
if (command === "COMMAND") {
        var VC = message.member.voiceChannel;
        if (!VC)
            return message.reply("MESSAGE IF NOT IN A VOICE CHANNEL")
    VC.join()
        .then(connection => {
            const dispatcher = connection.playFile('c:/PAtH/TO/MP3/FILE.MP3');
            dispatcher.on("end", end => {VC.leave()});
        })
        .catch(console.error);
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for contributing to the answer thread. Would you like me to edit this into the answer or leave it separate

Comment: Its up to you, I am happy either way :)

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead an included Nicholas Johnson's [Github bot code](https://github.com/NickJohn547745/DiscordBotSpeak) here, but I made slight modifications.

1. He appears to be creating a lock; so I created a `LockableClient` that extends the Discord [`Client`](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/client/Client.js).
2. Never include an authorization token in the code

#### auth.json

```
{
  "token" : "your-token-here"
}
```

#### lockable-client.js

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js')

/**
 * A lockable client that can interact with the Discord API.
 * @extends {Client}
 */
class LockableClient extends Client {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options)
    this.locked = false
  }
  lock() {
    this.setLocked(true)
  }
  unlock() {
    this.setLocked(false)
  }
  setLocked(locked) {
    return this.locked = locked
  }
  isLocked {
    return this.locked
  }
}

module.exports = LockableClient;
```

#### index.js

```js
const auth = require('./auth.json')
const { LockableClient } = require('./lockable-client.js')

const bot = new LockableClient()

bot.on('message', message => {
  if (!bot.isLocked() && message.content === 'Gotcha Bitch') {
    bot.lock()
    var voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
      const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./assets/audio/gab.mp3')
      dispatcher.on('end', end => voiceChannel.leave());
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    bot.unlock()
  }
})

bot.login(auth.token)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an semi old thread but I'm going to add code here that will hopefully help someone out and save them time. It took me way too long to figure this out but `dispatcher.on('end')` didn't work for me. I think in later versions of discord.js they changed it from `end` to `finish`

```
var voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;
    voiceChannel.join()
        .then(connection => {
            const dispatcher = connection.play(fileName);
            dispatcher.on("finish", end => {
                voiceChannel.leave();
                deleteFile(fileName);
            });
        })
        .catch(console.error);
```

Note that fileName is a string path for example: fileName = "/example.mp3". Hopefully that helps someone out there :)

Comment: Delete file is not defined, please fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Update: If you want to detect if the Audio has stopped, you must subscribe to the `speaking` event.

```js
voiceChannel
    .join()
    .then((connection) => {
        const dispatcher = connection.play("./audio_files/file.mp3");

        dispatcher.on("speaking", (speaking) => {
            if (!speaking) {
                voiceChannel.leave();
            }
        });
    })
```