# How to create a Discord bot which simply plays local audio files into your channel?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I was wondering how to create such a Discord bot, playing music files stored in my PC (and not from any internet source like youtube...).
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580798/how-to-play-audio-file-into-channel) solution, but some corrections have to be made for discord.js v12

Comment: You're expected to attempt this first before asking for help, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. [Refer to this for a list of v11 to v12 changes](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html?v=12)

Comment: ok, so giving my code which correct old code is not well received, noted !

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you were answering your own question Lol, I take back my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a simply code I made for discord v12. (Note that I'm a fresh beginner in javascript, so if any mistake is made, please tell me)

**settings.json**

```
{
  "token" : "{YOUR TOKEN}",
  "filesDir" : "./files/",
  "commandPlay" : ["!playLocal", "!playlocal"],
  "commandStop" : ["!stopLocal", "!stoplocal"],
  "commandList" : ["!playLocal list", "!playlocal list"],
  "warningPlayArgsSentence" : "Aucun argument renseigné, veuillez informer du titre du fichier à jouer. Exemple : !playLocal FoxMix",
  "filesListSentence" : "Liste des fichiers .mp3 disponibles : ",
  "warningFolderNotFoundSentence" : "Ce répertoire semble être impossible à scanner : " 
}
```

**index.js**

```
const settings = require('./settings.json')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs');

var isReady = true;

const bot = new Discord.Client();

function startsWithInList(message, list) {
  var found = false;
  list.forEach(function (item) {
    if( message.startsWith(item) ) {
      found = true;
    }
  })
  return found;
}

function foundsInList(message, list) {
  var found = false;
  list.forEach(function (item) {
    if( message === item ) {
      found = true;
    }
  })
  return found;
}

bot.on( 'message', message => {
  if( foundsInList(message.content, settings.commandList) ) {
    fs.readdir( settings.filesDir, function (err, files) {
      if(err) {
        return message.channel.send(settings.warningFolderNotFoundSentence+settings.filesDir);
      } 
      let listTxt = "";
      files.forEach(function (file) {
        if( file.endsWith('.mp3') || file.endsWith('.MP3') ) {
          listTxt += `\`${file.split('.')[0]}\` `;
        }
      })
      message.channel.send(settings.filesListSentence);
      message.channel.send(listTxt);
    })
    return;
  }
  if( isReady && startsWithInList(message.content, settings.commandPlay) ) {
    isReady = false;
    const args = message.content.slice(10).trim().split(' ');
    if( args.length != 1 || !args[0] || args[0] === "" ) {
      return message.channel.send(settings.warningPlayArgsSentence);
    }
    var voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    voiceChannel.join().then( connection => {
      const dispatcher = connection.play(settings.filesDir+args[0]+'.mp3')
      dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
        voiceChannel.leave();
        isReady = true;  
      })
    });
  }
  if ( startsWithInList(message.content, settings.commandStop) ) {
    message.member.voice.channel.leave();
    isReady = true;
  }
})

bot.login(settings.token);
```

For those who are lost and never made a bot :

1. Look on the net for "How to create a discord bot"
2. Download ffmpeg binaries (which will be placed in working folder) + Install node.js from the net
3. run in Windows PowerShell

> npm init

> npm install discord.js

> npm install -g windows-build-tools

> npm install node-opus

And finaly, create a folder called "files" in working directory and put your .mp3 into.
Run with

```
node .\index.js
```

And test the "!playLocal musicFile" discord comment